# May a landlord (having already paid the fine) seek damages from the actual perpetrator?

Tags: canada, liability, landlord, damages, tort

If a tenant unintentionally causes a false fire alarm, and building management pays the fine (and associated expenses), what legal grounds would the building have to come after the tenant for reimbursement?

Comment: Can you clarify/cite the particular law you are being fined under, and the details of whether or not it applies in light of your adverb "unintentionally?"

Comment: @WBT, it seems to be some description here: [link](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/sim/en/fee-schedule-and-building-categories). The funny part of this is they've charged 750$ by police, so it was at least 3rd incident there! I have no problem with paying police fine, there is other charges that hurt me and give me a sense of being black mailed!

Comment: Does it say anything in your tenancy agreement about liability for fines and what they may or may not charge you?

Comment: @Rup since its office of my employer, I dont have access to agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Montreal but, in general, public policy doesn't allow other people to be forced to pay your fines.

The building owner was accused, pleaded guilty (implicitly by paying the fine) and incurred the fine. They *should* have pleaded *not guilty* and put forward that you were the perpetrator. By not doing so, they have prejudiced your ability to defend the case against you (innocent triggering *may* be a defence).

If you were to dispute the claim on you, I believe they would have a hard time proving you owe them anything.

Comment: wow. Interesting. So, I think I should talk to them from another perspective. Till now I was thinking about if they can charge me for such non-sense. Thanks @DaleM

Comment: @KiNG You might want to hire a lawyer and let them talk to your landlord. Just a single letter with a lawyer's letterhead can often end such disputes rather gracefully.

Comment: @Philipp I'll consider this option if my next meeting with them fail. Thanks :)

Comment: @KiNG This answer makes a lot of assumptions about the law under which the fine was imposed. It might be that the property owner is legally liable for the fine regardless of who is responsible for the false alarm. If that's the case then this answer is incorrect.

Comment: It could also be that there are consequences if the fine isn't paid like "we want respond to another fire alarm until the fine is paid". In which case all the innocent tenants would be very annoyed if the landlord didn't pay immediately.

Comment: @phoog only one assumption - I can't be punished for your crime and you can't be punished for mine. If you have an example of a law where this doesn't apply I would love to see it.

Comment: Property owners in New York City are responsible for keeping their sidewalks clean and in good repair. If someone else, including a tenant, leaves trash on the sidewalk, the landlord is still responsible.  I can easily imagine a similar arrangement for false alarms.

Comment: See http://www.cityofvancouver.us/police/page/false-alarm-reduction-program for one scheme in which false alarms result in fines for the "alarm owner."

Comment: @phoog sure, but that is the landlord's offence - *they* are required to keep the sidewalk clean. There is, no doubt, a *separate* offence for littering. The landlord has no claim on the litterer for the fine, only ;or the costs of cleaning up.